# I would like to have Excel 365 make a table with each field being a Friday in the month based on the starting date. Why is it pulling the day before?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am making a spreadsheet for my personal financial needs and my table initiates with June 1, a Saturday.

I am using the formula `=U1-WEEKDAY(U1)+6` to calculate each Friday for payday.

In my table, the formula is entered where the 5/31 is displaying. For the subsequent dates, I am taking the cell above +7. I am unsure as to why the same formula I've used elsewhere would cause the first record to be 5/31 in just this table, the day BEFORE the initial seed date. 5/31 is already factored in for the month of May.

I would appreciate any insight into what I did wrong so I can fix it.

The formula for the other 11 months of the year.

Problem Table:
[image: Problem Table]

Comment: You  formula always results in the previous day for any given Saturday. Could it be that June is the only month you have (so far) where the first day is a Saturday? Doing a search for "Excel first Friday in month" gives multiple results on ways to get the first Friday in any given month

Answer (score 0):

You said you are using the formula `=U1-WEEKDAY(U1)+6` with the date in cell `U1` being a Saturday. To answer your question, you need to work out what `WEEKDAY(U1)` would return.

The Excel `WEEKDAY()` function takes a date and returns a number between 1-7 representing the day of week. By default, WEEKDAY returns 1 for Sunday and 7 for Saturday.  Therefore, in your case `WEEKDAY(U1)` would return a 7.  This would turn your formula into the calculation of `U1-7+6`.

One area that trips me up sometimes is that [Excel does not follow the true BODMAS rule](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/bodmas-gone-mad-excel-2010/5c9f625e-15c5-420e-a83a-f575e0d796f8).  It follows the formula from left to right unless there are brackets.  It will calculate everything in brackets left to right first, and then calculate the rest left to right. If it followed BODMAS, it would return a result of `U1-13`.
In Excel your formula would give you a result of `U1-1` (the previous day).

If `U1` was a Wednesday, it would be `U1-4+6` which would give you 2 days after the day in `U1`.  Do you see what the formula is doing?

The formula is working out what date the Friday is in the Sunday-Saturday week for the date given in `U1`.

If you want the Friday in the week following the date in `U1` you could enclose the current formula in brackets and add 7 at the making the formula `=(U1-WEEKDAY(U1)+6)+7`

There would be a problem though with this formula.  If you change your start date to a Wednesday, it will advance the first payday to the Friday in the following week thereby missing a payday.

If you wish to use your original formula, you will need to use an `IF()` function to check if `U1` is Friday or before first.

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(U1)=<6,U1-WEEKDAY(U1)+6,(U1-WEEKDAY(U1)+6)+7
```

A more efficient formula to use (short and without `IF()` functions) is

=U1+(7-WEEKDAY(U1,2)+5)

The `,2` in the `WEEKDAY()` function changes the weekday format from Sunday-Saturday to Monday-Sunday with Monday = 1

Comment: If I use "=IF(WEEKDAY(U1)=<6,U1-WEEKDAY(U1)+6,(U1-WEEKDAY(U1)+6)+7" in other places in the spreadsheet to prevent this "error" from happening again, would this formula break the rest of my spreadsheet? This table is one of twelve for the entire year and this can't be the only time this ever happens.

Comment: @CrystalCollins - If the spreadsheet layout is the same then you can use it in all the sheets